# Algorithm to print the total sum of all the path

Tags: algorithm, recursion, binary-tree, non-recursive

Giving you a binary tree which defined as follows:

```
public class TreeNode {
    public int val;
    public TreeNode left, right;

    public TreeNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = this.right = null;
    }
}
```

print the total sum of all the path, a path is defined as the line from the root node to any leaf node

For example:

> 4 5 6 7 8 10 # # # # 9

should return:

path1: 4 + 5 + 7

path2: 4 + 5 + 8 + 9

path3: 4 + 6 + 10

so the total path sum should be: path1 + path2 + path3

how can we solve the problem by using

- recursive
- non-recursive

I have find a solution by using non-recursive, but have some little problem about recursive method

Non-Recursive Method:

```
/**
 * non-recursive
 */
public static int pathSum2(TreeNode root) {
    int sum = 0;
    if (root == null) {
        return sum;
    }
    Queue<TreeNode> queueNode = new LinkedList<TreeNode>();
    Queue<Integer> queueSum = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    queueNode.add(root);
    queueSum.add(root.val);
    while (!queueNode.isEmpty()) {
        TreeNode node = queueNode.poll();
        int temp = queueSum.poll();
        if (node.left == null && node.right == null) {
            sum += temp;
        }
        if (node.left != null) {
            queueNode.add(node.left);
            queueSum.add(node.left.val + temp);
        }
        if (node.right != null) {
            queueNode.add(node.right);
            queueSum.add(node.right.val + temp);
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Recursive Method:

```
/**
 * recursive
 */
public List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root) {
    List<List<Integer>> rst = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    helper(rst, new ArrayList<Integer>(), root);
    return rst;
}

public void helper(List<List<Integer>> rst, ArrayList<Integer> list,
                   TreeNode root) {
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }
    list.add(root.val);
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        rst.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
    }
    helper(rst, list, root.left);
    helper(rst, list, root.right);
    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```

but in this way, what I have output is all the path, what if I want to get the total sum of those path?

One way to get the answer is iterator the List> and get the answer but I think it's inefficient. How can we deal with this just in the `helper()` method because for the sum, java is just `pass-by-value`

Comment: What have you tried? It will be easier for people to help you out if they can see what you've tried so far and specifically which part of the problem you are struggling with

Comment: Smells like a homework problem

Comment: Just giving you a rough guide, bc I really believe that's an assignment:
Just traverse the tree in pre-order and each time you process a node you add its value to `List<Integer>` which you can either pass to the recursive function by reference or declare it as an instance/global variable. If you are processing a leaf node: print the list. If you "leave" a node: delete its value from the list.

Comment: @br3w5 I have add my code about recursive method, but I am a little confusing about how to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find a solution by using recursive

```
/**
 * recursive
 */
public List<List<Integer>> pathSum(TreeNode root, int sum) {
    List<List<Integer>> rst = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    helper(rst, new ArrayList<Integer>(), root, sum);
    return rst;
}

public void helper(List<List<Integer>> rst, ArrayList<Integer> list,
                   TreeNode root, int sum) {
    if (root == null) {
        return;
    }
    list.add(root.val);
    if (root.left == null && root.right == null) {
        rst.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(list));
    }
    helper(rst, list, root.left, sum - root.val);
    helper(rst, list, root.right, sum - root.val);
    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```